# count words y sq and posgresql

Tags: sql

I have a database of information that looks like this:

| name | roles |
| --- | --- |
| roman | art director, publicist, chairman |
| daniel | director of art, publicist and economist |
| hugo | director of art, economist, doctor and publicist |

I have tried this to filter all those rows that have 2 or more roles, but it is only filtering the comma-delimited ones.

1. How can I include the cases where there is a stopword like "and" but not include the stopword "of"
2. When I try to filter by a condition keeps telling me that the count column does not exist how could I find the 2 or more words condition?

```html
SELECT roles, SUM(length(roles) - length(replace(roles, ',', '')) +1) 
    AS TotalCount
FROM directors
GROUP BY roles
HAVING TotalCount > 3
```

Comment: please share sample data.

Comment: thank you! didnt realise the table didnt paste. I edited the original post.

Comment: This is a flawed schema design. Better design uses an additional table, where each role for a person has it's own record.

Comment: agree, but how to deal with it if you can´t change it?

Comment: This isn't regular data, for the formal definition of regular (think "regular expressions"), and so what you're asking for is functionally the same as asking for a natural language processor. You might find a heuristic that works for your data, but the only way to know is to test and validate it against **ALL** your data, to be sure you've correctly identified all your actual edge cases. We can't do that for you from a 3 record sample.

Comment: what if your role is "head of people and culture" or similar?

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate 'and' from the condition you can use
replace(roles,'and',','))

```
SELECT roles, SUM(length(replace(roles,'and',',')) - length(replace(replace(roles,'and',','), ',', '')) +1) 
    AS TotalCount
FROM directors
GROUP BY roles
HAVING TotalCount > 3
```

Comment: @elisa Please let me know if you are still facing difficulties with your query.